# How can  I disable screen lock feature temporarily?

Tags: lock-screens

I want to lend a tablet to a friend of mine and I'm sure he will try to prank me with a locked screen.

What can I do to remove the screen lock, if he returns it with the locked screen feature enabled with a code or something?

Comment: What makes you think he'll stop at locking the screen? Maybe he'll root the phone and install a key logger, also.

Comment: There's a saying in security: physical access is root (admin) access. Anything that you do to try and prohibit him can be easily circumvented if he is really intent on doing something malicious.

Comment: I'm sorry, why are you lending a tablet to someone who you believe is going to mess with it? He may be a friend, but if you feel it's likely that he's going to intentionally do things to your tablet, then don't lend it to him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to prevent this is to create an extra guest profile with help from SwitchMe:

**Get root, install [SwitchMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.switchme), create an guest profile, protect your profile with an password and enable SwitchMe's login manager feature.** This allows you to recover the tablet by rebooting into your profile and resetting or deleting the guest profile.

Note that SwitchMe may not work with your ROM.